# Different document length for a Neurips 2021 paper on Overleaf versus Texlive on Linux

Tags: compiling, overleaf, texlive-2020

I have run into a strange behavior with the style file of Neurips 2021 (a conference), [available here](https://neurips.cc/Conferences/2021/PaperInformation/StyleFiles). If I compile their sample TeX file on Overleaf, I get more content on the same number of pages, compared to when I compile it locally on my Machine, an Arch Linux system with TexLive 2020. Below are the screenshots:

On my computer:
[image]

On Overleaf:
[image]

This matters since the conference has a 9-page limit and I get get more in 9 pages if I compile on Overleaf. Any idea why this happens and if there is a fix for it (i.e., to get a similar result as Overleaf locally)?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598575/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that was quick:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so slow ;-)

Comment: Thanks, interesting, glad that this has already been addressed!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Yes, that seems to address the issue. I suggest adding a NeurIPS 2021 tag or just this word (or something similar) to the title of that post so that it is easier to find. I have one more question. So is the conclusion that the Overleaf is using an older distribution or is it us?

Comment: overleaf is using an "early" texlive 2020, the change in the format that affected this  happened during texlive 2020 cycle, so shows in an updated 2020 or in texlive 2021 so it won't show in overleaf until they roll out 2021. The organisers could update the package, it only needs three lines adding, It would save a lot of questions....

Comment: @passerby51 I updated the title in the earlier question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, great! Thanks.

Comment: @passerby51 the previous OP said he had contacted them but it wouldn't hurt if you gave the conference organisers a nudge

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I agree, will try to contact them too.